# Operation timed out in HtmlAgilityPack but opens in browser

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I get operation timed out when I load a page through HtmlAgilityPack in c#. I check the page in web browser and it opens fine. I don't understand how is this possible.

**More info**
For one website, htmlagilitypack works fine. And for other it shows operation timed out. Filpkart.com opens fine and Amazon.in gives operation timed out in htmlagailitypack. But in web browser they both open fine. Few days before, both sites were loading fine with htmlagailitypack.

Here is the code sample that I am using:

```
htmlDocument = htmlWeb.Load("http://www.amazon.in/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=" + current_isbn);
                    getNode = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//h3[contains(@class,'newaps')]/a");
                    if (getNode != null)
                    {
                        htmlDocument = htmlWeb.Load(getNode.Attributes["href"].Value);
...
```

Sometimes I get `System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out.` when document is loaded for `htmlDocument = htmlWeb.Load("http://www.amazon.in/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=9780141327679");` and sometimes for `htmlDocument = htmlWeb.Load(getNode.Attributes["href"].Value);`

Comment: Please help, how can this issue be resolved.

Comment: For one website, htmlagilitypack works fine. And for other it shows operation timed out. Filpkart.com opens fine and Amazon.in gives operation timed out in htmlagailitypack. But in web browser they both open fine. Few days before, both sites were loading fine with htmlagailitypack.

Comment: you're not telling us anything constructive here. Post the code you have done, point us to the website you are testing your code one, tell us the exact error you are getting (exception, inner exception etc....)

Comment: I have added the code sample. Document loading works well for flipkart.com but not for amazon.in in htmlagailitypack. Although they both open in web browser without any time out.

Comment: Have you analyzed the web request(s) using fiddler http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler ?